# Geometric Interpretation of Laplace's Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic.  In the natural way, let $f = u + vi$ for $u,v : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$.  Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Suppose that $u$ and $v$ satisfy Laplace's equation at $z$ (which they do since $f$ is analytic) so that

$$
\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$

and

$$
\Delta v = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$

**Question 1:** Does this mean that the real and complex parts of $f''(z)$ are equal to each other in magnitude?

---

EDIT: This is why I think that the Laplace Equations holding for $u$ and $v$ implies that $f''(z)$ has real and complex components which are equal in magnitude to each other.

1. Since $f$ is analytic, we have that the Cauchy-Riemann Equations hold for $u$ and $v$.  In particular, we have that

   $$
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v }{\partial y}
   $$

   and

   $$
   \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
   $$
2. This then means that $f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.
3. Then $\color{red}{f''(z) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} - i \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}}$.
4. Yet since $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$ via Laplace, we have that $f''(z)$ satisfies that its real and complex parts are equal in magnitude to each other.

Is this correct?

---

**Question 2:** If no to the above answer, what is a geometric interpretation of this statement?

Comment: See math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian.

Comment: Why do you think that it would imply that the real and complex parts of $f''(z)$ are equal in magnitude?

Comment: Bruno Joyal -- I answered your question by editing my post above.    Is my reasoning not correct?

Comment: You've got some faulty algebra in your edit. (I'll be using $\frac{da}{db}=a_b$ notation for LaTeX brevity.) If $f_z=u_x+iv_x$, then $f_{zz}=u_{xx}+iv_{xx}=u_{xx}-iu_{xy}=u_{xx}-iv_{yy}\neq u_{xx}-iu_{yy}$. You have to switch back to $v$. I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I hope this clears up the confusion surrounding both your questions.